# Multiple transitions on same element not working

Tags: css

I have two transitions on the same element out of which one works as expected, but the other one doesn't work on hover. What can I do to get both the transitions working?

CSS CODE:

```
.ArrowNext
{
    top:40%;
    right:14%;  
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
    width:200px;
    height:200px;   
    position:absolute;  
    cursor:pointer;

    transition: right 1s; /* Wont work*/
    transition: background 1s;
}
.ArrowNext:hover
{
    right:11%; /* Wont work*/
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
```

Comment: Multiple transitions should be provided in a comma separated format and not one below other.

Comment: Modified the title and description to make the question a bit more clearer. Please feel free to roll-back if you feel any of the modification is incorrect.

Comment: In some cases `transition all` will come in handy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second declaration is overriding the first.

Instead of declaring multiple `transition`s separately, you declare them together:

```
transition : right 1s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
```

You should play with easing methods as well. They can really change the "feel" of the animation.

Also, don't forget about vender prefixes:

```
-webkit-transition : right 1s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
-moz-transition    : right 1s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
-o-transition      : right 1s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
transition         : right 1s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
```

Here is some great documentation on `transition`s: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

And since you're new to CSS you should check-out http://caniuse.com, it's a great resource for determining browser compatibility.

Comment: @PedroAlejandroMirCabrera You're welcome, I also updated with a couple things that may help you.

Comment: As the very resource (caniuse) you yourself quote documents, vendor prefixes are **not** required for `transition`, unless you want to support old versions of some browsers like Safari 5.1 (even then, you'd only need `-webkit-`). Also, your revised `transition` is not DRY because it repeats `1s ease-out`. It would thus be marginally better to specify those properties separately as `transition-duration`, 'transition-timing-function', and 'transition-property'.

Comment: @torazaburo The UI for caniuse.com defaults to a certain number of browser releases to show. There are options to see more browser versions and if you use it you'll see that `-o-` and `-moz-` are also used in older versions of Opera and Firefox (respectively). Good catch though, as I don't believe Microsoft ever implemented `-ms-transition`. Personally I think that the style you can more easily work with is the best to use.

Comment: @Jasper The operating assumption is that people keep browsers like Mozilla updated. Best practices in the industry, as far as I am aware, do not involve accommodating people who have explicitly turned off the auto-update feature for browsers like Mozilla or Chrome and are stuck on old versions. This is not 2008. The exception is Safari, which is burnt into mobile devices, or engines burnt into e-book readers, which is why you will see people talking about prefixing to support old Safari version. If you want to include unnecessary `-moz-` prefixes, of course, no one will be the worse off.

Comment: @torazaburo `1)` Statistics mean nothing to an individual. I.e. if 1% of a user-base uses a browser, that doesn't mean nobody will visit your site with that version. `2)` Does everyone get to update their computer on a regular basis? Nope. They shouldn't be slighted from the full UI experience just because they don't have access to update the browser. `3)` The impact of adding more `transition` declarations is minimal if you're properly compressing the output. `4)` It feels arbitrary to say that old Safari is worth supporting but not old Mozilla `~)` Just my opinions, determined via experience

Comment: Unfortunately, what you say does not mesh with best practices at mainline webapp development companies, who assume that users with auto-updated browsers have the latest version. If someone reports a bug, the response is "why did you turn off auto-update, and turn it back on now". Boom, that's it. We got out of IE hell and into auto-update nirvana, take advantage of it. If you want to waste cycles catering to some tiny minority that is too stupid to press a button once in a while, feel free. It's not at all arbitrary to say we will worry about burnt-in browsers, but not auto-updating ones.

Comment: @torazaburo I've heard some pretty dumb things come from web design company reps so that certainly wouldn't sway me by itself (not to say I couldn't be swayed). In this case I feel like adding the extra declarations helps ensure happy users and is quite easy to implement. Which is why I don't see a reason to omit those declarations yet. Some browser compatibility issues are more complex and should probably be avoided if possible, this just isn't an area where I'd do that.